# ExecutionContext does not flow up the call stack from async methods

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, executioncontext

Consider the following code:

```cs
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await SetValueInAsyncMethod();
    PrintValue();

    await SetValueInNonAsyncMethod();
    PrintValue();
}

private static readonly AsyncLocal<int> asyncLocal = new AsyncLocal<int>();

private static void PrintValue([CallerMemberName] string callingMemberName = "")
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{callingMemberName}: {asyncLocal.Value}");
}

private static async Task SetValueInAsyncMethod()
{
    asyncLocal.Value = 1;
    PrintValue();

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}

private static Task SetValueInNonAsyncMethod()
{
    asyncLocal.Value = 2;
    PrintValue();

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

If you run this code inside a .NET 4.7.2 console application, you will get the following output:

```
SetValueInAsyncMethod: 1
Main: 0
SetValueInNonAsyncMethod: 2
Main: 2
```

I do understand that the differences in the output arise from the fact that `SetValueInAsyncMethod` is not really a method, but a state machine executed by `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder` which captures `ExecutionContext` internally and `SetValueInNonAsyncMethod` is just a regular method.

But even with this understanding in mind I still have some questions:

1. Is this a bug / missing feature or an intentional design decision?
2. Do I need to worry about this behavior while writing code that depends on `AsyncLocal`? Say, I want to write my `TransactionScope`-wannabe that flows some ambient data though await points. Is `AsyncLocal` enough here?
3. Are there any other alternatives to `AsyncLocal` and `CallContext.LogicalGetData` / `CallContext.LogicalSetData` in .NET when it comes down to preserving values throughout the "logical code flow"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this a bug / missing feature or an intentional design decision?

It's an intentional design decision. Specifically, the `async` state machine sets the "copy on write" flag for its logical context.

A correlation of this is that all *synchronous* methods belong to their closest ancestor `async` method.

> Do I need to worry about this behavior while writing code that depends on AsyncLocal? Say, I want to write my TransactionScope-wannabe that flows some ambient data though await points. Is AsyncLocal enough here?

Most systems like this use `AsyncLocal<T>` combined with an `IDisposable` pattern that clears the `AsyncLocal<T>` value. Combining these patterns ensures it will work with either synchronous or asynchronous code. `AsyncLocal<T>` will work fine by itself if the consuming code is an `async` method; using it with `IDisposable` ensures it will work with both `async` and synchronous methods.

> Are there any other alternatives to AsyncLocal and CallContext.LogicalGetData / CallContext.LogicalSetData in .NET when it comes down to preserving values throughout the "logical code flow"?

No.

Comment: Someone please explain this sentence in more details if you don't mind: "using it with IDisposable ensures it will work with both async and synchronous methods"

Comment: @Ostati: Setting `AsyncLocal<T>.Value` from a synchronous method actually changes the value for the first *asynchronous* method travelling up the call stack. So if `AAsync()` calls `B()` which sets `asyncLocal1.Value`, then `AAsync()` will see that updated value. Using `IDisposable` gives you an explicit scope within which that `AsyncLocal<T>.Value` update exists, and it is reset to its previous value when the disposable is disposed.

Comment: I still can't understand this situation completely. Could you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66500737/asynclocalt-doesnt-reach-controllers

Answer (score 7):

This seems like an intentional decision to me.

As you already know, `SetValueInAsyncMethod` gets compiled into a state-machine that implicitly captures the current ExecutionContext. When you change the `AsyncLocal`-variable, that change does not get "flowed" back to the calling function. In contrast, `SetValueInNonAsyncMethod` is not async and therefore not compiled into a state-machine. Therefore the ExecutionContext is not captured and any changes to `AsyncLocal`-variables are visible to the caller.

You can capture the ExecutionContext yourself as well, if you need this for any reason:

```
private static Task SetValueInNonAsyncMethodWithEC()
{
    var ec = ExecutionContext.Capture(); // Capture current context into ec
    ExecutionContext.Run(ec, _ => // Use ec to run the lambda
    {
        asyncLocal.Value = 3;
        PrintValue();
    });
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This will output a value of 3, while the Main will output 2.

Of course it is way easier to simply convert `SetValueInNonAsyncMethod` to async to have the compiler do this for you.

With regards to code that uses `AsyncLocal` (or `CallContext.LogicalGetData` for that matter), it is important to know that changing the value in a called async method (or any captured ExecutionContext) will not "flow back". But you can of course still access and modify the `AsyncLocal` as long as you do not reassign it.